# How to add background to text using MiniMagick::Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minimagick

I'm writing some text on an image with the help of **MiniMagick::Image**

**CODE**

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails.root}/a.png")

image.combine_options do |c|
  c.fill 'green'
  c.pointsize 20
  c.gravity 'center'
  c.draw "text 0,-110 'Hello I am here'"
  c.draw "text 150,-180 '#{Time.now}"
  c.background 'blue'
end

image.format 'pdf'
image.write("#{Rails.root}/b.pdf")
```

But, the background doesn't appear

I have referred [LINK1](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/minimagick/minimagick/MiniMagick%2FImage%3Acombine_options) & [LINK2](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I could get the `background` property to work:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails.root}/a.png")

image.combine_options do |c|
  c.gravity 'center'
  c.background 'lightgrey'
  c.splice "0x30"
  c.fill 'green'
  c.pointsize 20
  c.annotate '0', "Hello I am here"
  c.annotate '0', "#{Time.now}"
end

image.format 'pdf'
image.write("#{Rails.root}/b.pdf")
```